# How to request a small snippet of text via Android Intent from another of my own apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to setup an Intent in an Android application to request that another application (that I have also developed) send me back a small snippet of text. I see that with `startActivityForResult()` I can use an Intent to acquire a result from another activity.

My questions are:

- How do I setup an Intent to only "search" for my own applications?
- How do I check that the received Intent is from one of my own applications?
- Is there a better way to do this?

I was originally planning to add `android:sharedUserId` and make use of SharedPreferences but I absolutely cannot have my users [reinstall the application and lose their local data](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1227).

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about two different applications, the use of intent it's ok. Define your action and put a string extra in it. Send the intent from app A(string request) and receive the intent in B (the string "owner"). In broadcast receiver of B call setResult() to return your string. You have to call sendOrderedBroadcast() in app A.

Edit: in order to avoid to receive the intent from other apps, you can define your own permission in app B, define and use the permission in app A and in the broadcast recevier of B specify the permission in the parameters. When you define the permission you can specify "signature". In this way you are sure the "other" app is ***your*** app.

Comment: This would involve more than two applications. I can't figure out how to set it up to be "secure".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define intent filter in manifest for that activity which want to return a result.

And then in 2nd app call that activity using `startActivityForResult()` via that defined intent filter action.

hope this way can help you..

Reference for intent filter & action
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/intent/android-intents-and-intent-filters-example/